# Filtering rows in R

Tags: r

I have a file (called data) with 1000 lines which looks like

```
ChrNum Base_Position Gene    
1    108 NotGene     
1    114 Gene     
1    160 NotGene
```

I have similar files in the directory so I wanted to write a function that will go through the file and give me the Base_Position of each gene

I wrote this function to do so

```
position <- apply(data,1,function(a) {
        #go along each row and see if col3 is "Gene"
    genes <- data[data[,3]=='Gene',]
        #give me the position
    genes.up <- genes[,2]
        return(genes.up)
})
```

but when I look at the result it is

```
> position                                       
#[1] 114 114 114
```

Where all the rows are filled with the answer I am looking for.
I can't get my head around what it is I've done wrong

Comment: May be this help `with(df, Base_Position[Gene=='Gene'])` . If there are multiple files, you could read them in a list.  Suppose `lst` is the list that have the datasets, `lst <- lapply(list.files(), read.table);lapply(lst, function(x) with(x, Base_Position[Gene=='Gene']))`

Comment: yeah that works! as long as the x in `with(x, Base_Position[Gene=='Gene']))` has already been defined,right? Would it be possible to keep the results of each different file separate though?

Comment: These are list elements.  If you want to save it as separate file, you can do `write.table` within the list itself.  Regarding the comment about defining it, you can make it as a function and change the arguments as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr works well for these sort of filter and return portions of data frame problems

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
return_positions <- function(filename) { 
    data <- fread(filename)
    output <- data %>% filter(Gene == 'Gene') %>% 
         select(Base_Position)
    return(output)
}
```

You should be able scale that function up by passing all file names to the above function.

```
list_of_output_tables <- sapply(all_filenames, return_positions)
```

[Edit] To include how to do this for many files. If they are reasonably large I like using fread from data.table to do this.

Comment: You could just leave out the assignment to output and return of output in the function.

Comment: True, I thought it might be clearer to OP what was being returned.

Comment: `fread` gives a data.table output.  So, perhaps, `setkey(data, Gene)['Gene']$Base_Position` would be `data.table` only solution

Comment: works nice, though for the `sapply(all_filenames, return_positions)` would that work say if I had 100+ files? My understanding is that you mean I type in the names of the files I want to look at

Comment: You can assign all your files in a directory that match some pattern using `list.files()`.  So before using sapply above you'd create all_filenames like this `all_filenames <- list.files('directory', '*.txt', full.names =T)` The result from sapply will then be a list of the Base_Positions for each file in all_filenames

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("sqldf")
require(sqldf)
position <- sqldf("select * from data where data.Gene = 'Gene' ")
```

Now you said you had multiple files. There are a number of ways to scale this up, from copy and pasting it to making it a function. It sounds like wrapping it into a function should suit your needs.

Comment: that threw up an error for me of `no such table: a`. Interesting thought, but not really sure how it is working.

Comment: @user3816990 really? That's extremely odd. Well just take out the references to `a` and use the actual object name. I'll update the solution tho it works this way for me. Perhaps `sqldf` is using a different default SQL syntax in your environment.